# How to lookup for a key in a std::map and iterate backwards

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, reverse-iterator

I have a `std::map` which holds pointers to a `class`.

I need to lookup a key and iterate backwards until I get to the first item.

`std::map::reverse_iterator` does not support the `std::map::find()` method, so I have made a workaround, decreasing the direct `iterator` until the item just before `begin()` and then deal with the first item outside of the loop.

Is there another way? Is there an `rfind()` method?

Below is the code I am using:

```
if( MnbObj->ParNoMapa.IsEmpty() && MnbObj->TipoMan == "D" ) // Desligou, procurar à frente
{
    // Trocar por iterator
    itFind = MapFind.find( itManobra->first );
    if( itFind != MapFind.end() )
    {
        ++itFind;

        while( itFind != MapFind.end() )
        {
            MnbFind = itFind->second;

            if( MnbFind->EqpId->UndSig == Unidade &&
                MnbFind->EqpId->CodOper == Equipamento )
            {
                if( MnbFind->TipoMan == "D" )
                {
                    Logger->AddLogEntry("Manobra "+itManobra->first+
                                  " faltou religamento antes de "+
                                  MnbFind->DtHoraMan.FormatString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"), evsDontCare);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if( !MnbFind->Reconhece.IsEmpty() )
                        MnbObj->ParNoMapa = itFind->first;
                    break;
                }
            }

            ++itFind;
        }
    }
}
else if( MnbObj->ParNoMapa.IsEmpty() && MnbObj->TipoMan == "L" ) // Ligou, procurar para trás
{
    itFind = MapFind.find( itManobra->first );
    if( itFind != MapFind.begin() )
    {
        --itFind;

        while( itFind != MapFind.begin() )
        {
            MnbFind = itFind->second;

            if( MnbFind->EqpId->UndSig == Unidade &&
                MnbFind->EqpId->CodOper == Equipamento )
            {
                if( MnbFind->TipoMan == "L" )
                {
                    Logger->AddLogEntry("Manobra "+itManobra->first+
                                 " faltou desligamento após "+
                                 MnbFind->DtHoraMan.FormatString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"), evsDontCare);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if( !MnbFind->Reconhece.IsEmpty() )
                        MnbObj->ParNoMapa = itFind->first;
                    break;
                }
            }

            --itFind;
        }
        // resolver o primeiro
        itFind = MapFind.begin();

        MnbFind = itFind->second;

        if( MnbFind->EqpId->UndSig == Unidade &&
            MnbFind->EqpId->CodOper == Equipamento )
        {
            if( MnbFind->TipoMan == "L" )
            {
                Logger->AddLogEntry("Manobra "+itManobra->first+
                             " faltou desligamento após "+
                             MnbFind->DtHoraMan.FormatString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss"), evsDontCare);
            }
            else
            {
                itManobra->second->ParNoMapa = itFind->first;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you do not need to iterate elements of a `map` to find a key. Looking from the back makes no difference as there is only a single element for any given key. The question is unclear.

Comment: Strictly speakin a map doesn't have a "first" item. Just values you can lookup and key/value pairs you can iterate over.

Comment: So maybe you can explain us better what you want to do.  Because maybe a map is not the right datatructure.

Comment: you need to show your code, a [mcve]. Its also unclear what problem you encountered, because if you really want you can use `std::find_if` to search for a key in a map backwards. No problem with that https://godbolt.org/z/4z6PofTEh. If I had to guess, I would say you are calling `std::find` with wrong arguments and misinterpret the error message, but impossible to tell unless you show your code

Comment: I am not iterating to find a key. I have only to begin iterate backwards from some key in the map. That is, as I found the key I have to iterate backwards making tests on the class which each map item have.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::map` class template does not allow duplicated keys. So, you can use the `find()` method to find the required key starting from the beginning of a map.

It seems you mean something like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, char> m =
    {
        { 65, 'A' }, { 66, 'B'}, { 67, 'C' }, { 68, 'D' }, { 69, 'E' }, { 70, 'F' }
    };

    int key = 68;

    auto it = m.find( key );

    if (it != std::end( m ))
    {
        for (auto first = std::reverse_iterator( std::next( it ) ), last = std::rend( m );
            first != last; ++first)
        {
            std::cout << "( " << first->first << ", '" << first->second << "' ) ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is:

```
( 68, 'D' ) ( 67, 'C' ) ( 66, 'B' ) ( 65, 'A' )
```

Or, the `for` loop can look like this:

```cpp
for (auto first = std::reverse_iterator( std::next( it ) ), last = std::rend( m );
    first != last; ++first)
{
    const auto &[key, value] = *first;
    std::cout << "( " << key << ", '" << value << "' ) ";
}
```

If you are using the `std::multimap` class template then, instead of the `find()` method, you can use the `upper_bound()` method.

If you want to find a key based on a value, you should use the standard `std::find_if()` algorithm. With that algorithm, you can use reverse iterators.

Comment: No, not at all. I am very sorry, may be you are not understanding  my english. The code I have posted does exactly what I want it to do. I just think it is not an elegant way of doing that.

Comment: The map key is a unicode string which contains a datetime value on the format "yyyymmddhhnnss" plus two data names, so it is ordered mainly by date time. If the class data value has a "on"(L) I must iterate backwards to discover what is the element which has the "Off"(D) value, because an "L" always come after a "D".

Comment: As long as you have closed my question I will keep the solution to the problem which I have made . Thank you anyway.